# Listview Drag and Drop - mouse vs touch

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, touch

Im having problems with WPF application where i have:
Wrap Panel as Items Panel in listbox which is (the listbox) in ScrollViewer. I also have lot of buttons which i can drag and drop. Problem is that it works fine when im using mouse, but not working when im running application in touch screen. Is there any property should i change so it will work in touchable screen?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have not did this ever but I think that for touchscreen you will have to use Stylus events. Like for Drag use StylusMove etc. I hope this will lead you to get an idea.